# AWS Cloudfront Cache Configuration

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So I have a application deployed to S3, with Cloudfront configured for distribution.

I deployed some updated features to S3 however they have not taken effect yet and it's about a day since I pushed the update.

My question is how should I configure the cache settings in Cloudfront so that my updates will take effect? I have referenced articles to try and correct the issue however no luck so far.

*Note if I click the root url in S3 my updates to appear which tells me that this is a cache issue, if not please let me know..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

On cloud front there should be caching from the origin and please understand one thing for Example I have main.js in my  S3 bucket and I made some changes to main.js that same file in that case as that file is already cached to your CDN (here CloudFront) it not going to update automatically you have to invalidate the CloudFront distribution .

You don't need to do this if you are uploading a new file to your S3 bucket .

New files get cached automatically but changes didn't.
Please follow this document to Invalidate the current cache and wait for sometime it will fix your problem.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html
Please let me know if there is any issue I can help you with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one time update then simply create a new invalidation for all objects in CloudFront.
Note, if the objects were served with cache-control or expiry header then they could be cached at the browser level.